# How to set firebase app locale on the client SDK?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the [Authentication blocking triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/auth-blocking-events#getting_user_and_context_information) documentation at the context information it says that it contais a "locale", which can be set through the client SDK, or by passing the locale header in the REST API.
What's exactly this app locale, and where can I set it in the Web SDK?

I can't find any information about this app locale in the firebase documentation, but searched through the whole site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Auth.languageCode`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth.md#authlanguagecode), for example:

```js
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"

const auth = getAuth()
auth.languageCode = 'fr'

// To apply the default browser preference instead of explicitly setting it:
// auth.useDeviceLanguage();

// your other client code goes here
```